# Django url.py regex not working

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x

I am trying to catch all URLs from the safer app and send them to a catch all view; for example:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/saferdb/123
http://127.0.0.1:8000/saferdb/12

I think I have an issue with my reg ex in url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'saferdb'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Views.py is the sample code from the django tutorial:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.DOT_Number for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)


def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)
```

I noticed that /saferdb/ will not work unless the reg ex contains a slash:
r'^/$' instead of r'^$' as shown in the django tutorial.

Comment: Show your main project urls.py.

Comment: add a `/` at the end of the **/saferdb** in the main urls.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add '/' at the end of url in root urls.py of 'safer' app, something similar to this:

```
url(r'^saferdb/', include('saferdb.urls', namespace='saferdb'))
```